Panic on Solana cross program invocation
Program log: panicked at 'range end index 64 out of range for slice of length 0', src/token.rs:551:38,
failed: SBF program panicked
Where can I investigate 551:38 line of code, or any help on debugging this internal panic?
My request looks like:
    invoke_signed(
        &Instruction {
            program_id: *jupiter_program.key,
            accounts,
            data,
        },
        &accounts_infos,
        &[],
    )

and where the accounts comes from Jupiter swap tx instruction
    let accounts: Vec<AccountMeta> = remaining_accounts
        .iter()
        .map(|acc| AccountMeta {
            pubkey: *acc.key,
            is_signer: acc.is_signer,
            is_writable: acc.is_writable,
        })
        .collect();

    let accounts_infos: Vec<AccountInfo> = remaining_accounts
        .iter()
        .map(|acc| AccountInfo { ..acc.clone() })
        .collect();

